# What is a basis of the polynomials in two variables $X_1, X_2$ over K as K-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to undertsand the notion of a basis when working with K-algebras.

Am I right that a K-algebra would be generated by $1,X_1$ and $X_2$?

I read somewhere that it is generated by $X_1$ and $X_2$ however I don't see why this should be true?

Comment: You are miing two thing: being a basis of an algebra and being a set of generators are rather dfferent things.

Comment: Yes! thank you! Indeed my preview formulation was wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra, and $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ elements of $A$. Then $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ generates $A$ as a $K$-algebra if for any $a\in A$ there is a polynomial $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ with coefficients in $K$ such that
$$
P(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=a
$$
in $A$. If, moreover, $P$ is unique for all $a$ then $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ is a basis of $A$ as a $K$-algebra.

The principal example of such a basis is $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ in $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. There is no problem for $1$ since $1=P(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ if one takes $P$ the constant polynomial $1$ in $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$.

Comment: Thank you. So the "problem" of field elements not being in the set of generators is solved by the definition of "being generated by". In the definition that you use the field elements are always generated by the set of generators because we can simply take constant polynomials?

Comment: This definition of basis is quite unusual...

Comment: I agree with @Mariano. This is the first time I have seen basis used like this (usually a basis of an algebra over a field is a basis of the underlying vector space).

Comment: Well, it is a basis as an algebra, not as a vector space.